# Get element back in completed event after Storyboard.Begin(element)

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

Must be something very simple, but already takes me dozens of minutes to solve. That's why asking.

```
    // start animation like this
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    ...
    storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
    storyboard.Begin(control); // << "control"


static void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = sender as Storyboard;
    ...
    // how to get "control" here?
}
```

I can use properties or perhaps create sort of `Tag` for storyboard (attached property?). But it just can't be so complicated for so obvious task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Completed` event is inherited from the [`Timeline.Completed` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can see that it uses a standard `EventArgs` object, so clearly, there is nowhere for it to store a reference to any control that may be used in an `Animation`.

The simplest way for you to get hold of a reference to the control that you applied your `Animation` on, is for you to define a private member variable in your class:

```
private UIElement animatedContol = null;
```

...

```
// start animation like this
var storyboard = new Storyboard();
...
storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
storyboard.Begin(control); 
animatedContol = control;
```

...

```
static void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = sender as Storyboard;
    ...
    // do something with animatedContol here
}
```

Comment: Animation is applied to a control inside custom control. Problem was `static` method (no `this`), but after your *reference to the control you applied animation* it become obvious: making non-static method, so that event handler become non-static too and I have `this` to my disposal. Thanks.

Comment: And what happen if you start it more than once without waiting with different controls as parameters? i really dislike how those storyboards are implemented.